# Stack overflow error when creating a database entry using Hibernate and springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a new database entry using Springboot hibernate and when I make the post request I get a 500 Internal Server Error on post man that says I have a stack over flow issue.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class AppUser {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Strategy> userStrategies;

    @Builder
    public AppUser(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public AppUser(){}
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Game {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer gameId;
    private String gameName;
    private String gameDescription;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Strategy> gameStrategies;

    public Game(){}

    @Builder
    public Game(String gameName, String gameDescription) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gameDescription = gameDescription;
    }
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Strategy {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String strategyName;
    private String strategyDescription;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "userId")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private AppUser appUser;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName ="gameId")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Game game;

    public Strategy(){}

    @Builder
    public Strategy(String strategyName, String strategyDescription, Game game, AppUser appUser) {
        this.strategyName = strategyName;
        this.strategyDescription = strategyDescription;
        this.appUser = appUser;
        this.game = game;
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class StrategyService {
    @Autowired
    private GameRepository gameRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private StrategyRepository strategyRepository;

    public Strategy creatStrategy(Strategy strategy, Integer userId, Integer gameId){
        Game game = gameRepository.findById(gameId).get();
        AppUser user = userRepository.findById(userId).get();

        Strategy newStrategy = Strategy.builder()
            .strategyDescription(strategy.getStrategyDescription())
            .strategyName(strategy.getStrategyName())
            .game(game)
            .appUser(user)
            .build();
        strategyRepository.save(newStrategy);
        return newStrategy;

    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class StrategyController {
    @Autowired
    private StrategyRepository strategyRepository;

    @PostMapping("/strategy/user/{userId}/game/{gameId}")
    public Strategy creatStrategy(
        @RequestBody Strategy strategy,
        @PathVariable Integer userId, 
        @PathVariable Integer gameId 
        ){
            Strategy newStrategy= creatStrategy(strategy, userId, gameId);
            return newStrategy;
        }
}
```

I tried using the @ToString.Exclude and @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"gameStrategies", "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"}, allowSetters = true) on all the relationships that are joining but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: please provide the stacktrace of the stackoverflow error